# Javascript String to Property

Tags: javascript

How can I get the method eg: "background" of an Object/element from string "background"? [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tpahadi/ajqcv1u0/1/)
Here is my method that looks kind of jQuery:

```
 var $ = function css(selector,myStyle,value){
    var p = document.querySelectorAll("selector");
    for(var i = 0; i<x.length; i++){
        //This Works
        x[i].style.background = "#0489B1";

        //This doesn't
        //x[i].style.myStyle = "#0489B1";
    }
}
```

How can I call it using?

```
$(".example","background","blue");
```

Comment: And look at the allowed properties, it's not the same as css exactly - http://www.sitestepper.be/en/css-properties-to-javascript-properties-reference-list.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for indexer notation:

```
x[i].style[myStyle] = value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to access it using `box brackets` and not the `dot` notation.

`x[i].style[myStyle] = "#0489B1"`

When you use the `dot` notation, it looks for a property named `myStyle` in the `style` object which doesn't exist.

When you use the brackets, the value in the `myStyle` parameter is resolved first and then the expression is evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

The object properties can be accessed with dot notation and with square brackets notation:

```
function $(selector,myStyle,value){
    var p = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    for(var i = 0; i<x.length; i++){
        //This Works
        p[i].style[myStyle] = value;
    }
}
```

Annotated ECMAScript 5.1 
[11.2.1 Property Accessors](https://es5.github.io/#x11.2.1)